# Odd behaviour when trying to get json object array into knockout observable array (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7kv0d3t6/1/

Note I am purposely loading two separate observable arrays: programmeList & programmeList2.

I don't understand why the mapping version doesn't work:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, ViewModel.programmeList);
```

And the really odd thing is that the html databound span showing length:

```
<span data-bind="text: programmeList().length"></span>
```

...shows "5" and yet doesn't show anything in either the html (should at least show the table headings, right?) OR in the console.log output.

If I change the html code to use programmeList2 it does show the table, but I'd rather do it using the mapping plugin way and I'd like to understand the anomalies it's showing in my fiddle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are missing an `=` here:

```
<p data-bind="if: programmeList().length = 0">
<!--                                     ^ should be ==       -->
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/7kv0d3t6/2/) works.

Comment: Oh my good god I am such an idiot!  All this time it's been working but I've been reassigning the damn value!  Well spotted... and sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Comment: Many js linters have warnings for these kinds of errors (i.e. a single `=` within an `if` block). Moving the logic to your viewmodel usually helps in avoiding typo's like these. E.g.: `this.hasProgrammes = ko.pureComputed(() => this.programmeList().length > 0)`

Comment: Some people recommend to write constants first so that you get an error if you are missing an equals sign (`if: 0 = programmeList().length`)